# Node js: Error: Cannot find module 'mime-types/node_modules/mime-db'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, crud

I followed a [tutorial](https://codeburst.io/writing-a-crud-app-with-node-js-and-mongodb-e0827cbbdafb) to create a CRUD App with Nodejs, I finished the project and everything worked fine. After I tried to move all the files and folders to a new folderand I destroyed everything.

Now when I try to run node app.js the following happen:

```
enter code herinternal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'mime-types/node_modules/mime-db'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Costis\Documents\Code\Vue\Mongodb_app\server\node_modules\mime-types\index.js
- C:\Users\Costis\Documents\Code\Vue\Mongodb_app\server\node_modules\accepts\index.js
- C:\Users\Costis\Documents\Code\Vue\Mongodb_app\server\node_modules\express\lib\request.js
- C:\Users\Costis\Documents\Code\Vue\Mongodb_app\server\node_modules\express\lib\express.js
- C:\Users\Costis\Documents\Code\Vue\Mongodb_app\server\node_modules\express\index.js
- C:\Users\Costis\Documents\Code\Vue\Mongodb_app\server\app.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:794:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Costis\Documents\Code\Vue\Mongodb_app\server\node_modules\mime-types\index.js:15:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Costis\\Documents\\Code\\Vue\\Mongodb_app\\server\\node_modules\\mime-types\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Costis\\Documents\\Code\\Vue\\Mongodb_app\\server\\node_modules\\accepts\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Costis\\Documents\\Code\\Vue\\Mongodb_app\\server\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\request.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Costis\\Documents\\Code\\Vue\\Mongodb_app\\server\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\express.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Costis\\Documents\\Code\\Vue\\Mongodb_app\\server\\node_modules\\express\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Costis\\Documents\\Code\\Vue\\Mongodb_app\\server\\app.js'
  ]e
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Some hidden files may not be copied. Try deleting `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again to install dependencies.

Comment: @imvpn22 Thanks for your answer. I tried to delete it but now I have a new error `(events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

ReferenceError: next is not defined)`

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to make a clean install your dependencies again with `npm install`, as you might have broken some symlinks (just assuming as I'm not a Windows user).

You can manually delete your `node_modules` folder and run `npm install`, or if you have an existing `package-lock.json`, use [`npm ci`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html) to install exactly the same versions of deps you had before.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried and now the server is running but when I try to connect for example to local http://localhost:1234/students/test  throws a new error :
`events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

ReferenceError: next is not defined`